# Did I kill my brother with a bug or an extremely lucky shot?

Tags: quake-2

I was playing Quake 2 with my brother on [the edge](http://quake.wikia.com/wiki/Q2DM1:_The_Edge) map. I had run from weapon to weapon finding they were all gone. Finally, I was able to pick up a super shotgun and some shells and made it into the outside room where the railgun pool was.

My brother came out on that ledge with the rocket launcher. He fired his rocket launcher and apparently at the exact same moment, I fired my shotgun in a desperate attempt to cause *some* damage before I was gibbed.

Imagine both of our amazement, my delight, and his dismay when the very next thing that happened was his rocket exploded *right in his face*.

Naturally he went on to seek his own vengeance on me, but the experience has stuck with me for all these years.

*Was it a bug or a lucky shot?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lucky shot! You can shoot down the rockets as they are large enough projectiles, and they travel slow enough.

Me and a friend once shot each others rockets down when they collided, didn't realise it happened apart from someone else saw it and told us. We then tested it out and after 10 minutes or so we managed to replicate it... after a lot of 'accidents'!